# TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;comment_text&#39; of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I've declared a file called `commentSchema` which has some fields:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const moment = require('moment');


var commentSchema = new Schema ({
    comment_text: {type: String, required: true},
    user_token: {type: String, required: true},
    activity_id: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Activity', required: true },
    is_hidden: { type: Boolean, "default": false },
    created_at: { type: Number, "default": moment().unix() },
    updated_at: { type: Number, "default": moment().unix() }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);
```

and this is my router file:

```
var Router = require('router');
var router = Router();

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// importing Models
var userSchema = require('./models/userSchema.js');
var activitySchema = require('./models/activitySchema.js');
var commentSchema = require('./models/commentSchema');

// Parsing the informations get from the client
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));


router.get('/comments', (req, res) => {

});

router.post('/comment', (req, res) => {
    var newComment = {
        comment_text: req.body.comment_text,
        user_token: req.body.user_token,
        activity_id: req.body.activity_id
    }
    console.log(newComment);

    commentSchema.create(newComment, (err) => {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log('DONE!');
        }
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

I'm trying to send post request using `POSTMAN` but I get the following error:

`Cannot read property 'comment_text' of undefined`

[image]

Comment: Please share full router file contents.

Comment: @Er_sherlockian edited

Comment: Are you using the body-parser module? https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: @DannyDainton Yes I am. `var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of [router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/router). It says you have to use following:

```
router.use(bodyParser.json())
```